# C++: интерфейс без наследования

Tags: c++, наследование, интерфейс

Предположим, у меня есть абстрактный класс ("интерфейс") `I1` и конкретный тип `T`:

```
struct I1 {
  virtual void M1() = 0;
  virtual ~I1();
};

struct T {
  virtual void M1();

  T(){};
  virtual ~T(){};
};
```

Есть функция `f`, принимающая `I1`.

```
void f(I1& i1) {
  i1.M1();
}
```

Как видно, у `T` есть виртуальный метод `M1`, полностью повторяющий сигнатуру `I1.M1`. При этом, *`T` не наследуется от `I1`*.

Вопрос возможно глупый, но тем не менее. Можно ли каким-либо образом конвертировать объект типа `T` в тип `I1` и передать его в функцию `f`, чтобы внутри неё вызвался `T.M1`? Ответ "Нет, только через наследование" вполне приемлем.

Comment: Кастуйте, если уверены, что смещение M1 относительно адреса объекта будет совпадать для обоих классов. Но это неправильно.

Comment: Либо переходите на go - там такое поведение "из коробки". Впрочем, оно много ещё где.

Comment: @KoVadim, собственно, Go - мой основной язык. Решил вспомнить C++, и возник подобный вопрос. Видимо, ответ - не ходи со своим самоваром в чужую Тулу.

Comment: В Go нет такого поведения, там просто другая семантика для встроенных интерфейсов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так можно сделать только если `T` будет наследником `I1`. Альтернативным вариантом будет использование шаблонной функции `f`, с ограничением на то, каким может быть принимаемый объект типа `typename T`. Ограничение лучше всего делать с помощью концептов, которых пока в языке нет. Поэтому делать их придётся с использованием различных техник метапрограммирования. Но не ясно, насколько Вам это реально нужно, т.к. в большом количестве случаев можно обойтись просто неограниченным `T`, который даст ошибку компиляции, если у него нет соответствующей функции. Т.е. вот такой простой вариант:

```
template <typename I>
void f(I& i) {
  i.M1();
}
```